# Python3: In my morse code to Arduino LED Tkinter UI, the entry widget is not working properly

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pycharm, pyfirmata

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util

portX = input("What Port is the Arduino In? : ")

board = Arduino(portX)

iterator = util.Iterator(board)
iterator.start()

root = Tk()

MorseCodeDict = {'A': './-/|', 'B': '-/./././|',
                 'C': '-/./-/./|', 'D': '-/././|', 'E': './|',
                 'F': '././-/./|', 'G': '-/-/./|', 'H': '././././|',
                 'I': '././|', 'J': '.-/-/-/|', 'K': '-/./-/|',
                 'L': './-/././|', 'M': '-/-/|', 'N': '-/./|',
                 'O': '-/-/-/|', 'P': './-/-/./|', 'Q': '-/-/./-/|',
                 'R': './-/./|', 'S': './././|', 'T': '-/|',
                 'U': '././-/|', 'V': './././-/|', 'W': './-/-/|',
                 'X': '-/././-/|', 'Y': '-/./-/-/|', 'Z': '-/-/././|',
                 }

def English_to_Morse(eText):
    morseL = []
    for char in eText:
        if char in MorseCodeDict:
            morseL.append(MorseCodeDict[char] + "/")
    return " ".join(morseL)

led = board.get_pin('d:3:p')

root.geometry('1280x720')

entry = Entry(root, width=24)
entry.place(x=180, y=10)

morse = English_to_Morse(str(entry.get()).upper())

morseSplit = morse.split(" ")

def actLED():
    for x in range(len(morseSplit)):
        charSplit = morseSplit[x].split("/")
        charSplit.remove(charSplit[len(charSplit) - 1])
        for y in range(len(charSplit)):
            if charSplit[y] == ".":
                led.write(1)
                time.sleep(0.25)
                led.write(0)
            elif charSplit[y] == "-":
                led.write(1)
                time.sleep(0.50)
                led.write(0)
            elif charSplit[y] == "|":
                time.sleep(0.25)

message = Message(root, text="Enter Text to Turn to Morse Code: ", width=200)
message.configure(font=("Arial", 10))
message.place(x=0, y=10)

button = Button(root, text="Turn to Morse Code", command=actLED, width=20, height=2)
button.place(x=180, y=60)

root.mainloop()
```

Whenever I press the button, the entry never never has an output. I have tried "print(entry.get()), print(morse), print(morse), print(morseSplit), print(charSplit), etc., and they all come back with nothing. I have never come across this error before with tkinter; and it doesn't seem to raise any errors or anything. Also, it is 2:30 A.M. here in the UK right now; so sorry that this code is messy and uses brute-force for a couple of things.

Comment: You are calling `English_to_Morse()` *immediately* after creating the Entry - how could there possibly be any user input yet???  You need to do the entire `.get()` and conversion process from inside `actLED()`, so that it happens at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the order of your code and implemented the following two lines to your function `actLED()`.

```
morse =English_to_Morse(str(entry.get()).upper())
morseSplit = morse.split(" ")
```

As you can see with the print statements, there is now an input from your Entry which is processed.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
# from pyfirmata import Arduino, util

# portX = input("What Port is the Arduino In? : ")
# board = Arduino(portX)
# iterator = util.Iterator(board)
# iterator.start()

root = Tk()

MorseCodeDict = {'A': './-/|', 'B': '-/./././|',
                 'C': '-/./-/./|', 'D': '-/././|', 'E': './|',
                 'F': '././-/./|', 'G': '-/-/./|', 'H': '././././|',
                 'I': '././|', 'J': '.-/-/-/|', 'K': '-/./-/|',
                 'L': './-/././|', 'M': '-/-/|', 'N': '-/./|',
                 'O': '-/-/-/|', 'P': './-/-/./|', 'Q': '-/-/./-/|',
                 'R': './-/./|', 'S': './././|', 'T': '-/|',
                 'U': '././-/|', 'V': './././-/|', 'W': './-/-/|',
                 'X': '-/././-/|', 'Y': '-/./-/-/|', 'Z': '-/-/././|',
                 }

def English_to_Morse(eText):
    morseL = []
    for char in eText:
        if char in MorseCodeDict:
            morseL.append(MorseCodeDict[char] + "/")
    return " ".join(morseL)

# led = board.get_pin('d:3:p')

root.geometry('1280x720')

entry = Entry(root, width=24)
entry.place(x=180, y=10)

# morse = English_to_Morse(str(entry.get()).upper())
# morseSplit = morse.split(" ")

def actLED():
    morse = English_to_Morse(str(entry.get()).upper())
    morseSplit = morse.split(" ")
    print(morse)
    print(morseSplit)
    for x in range(len(morseSplit)):
        charSplit = morseSplit[x].split("/")
        charSplit.remove(charSplit[len(charSplit) - 1])
        print(charSplit)
        
        for y in range(len(charSplit)):
            if charSplit[y] == ".":
#                led.write(1)
                time.sleep(0.25)
#                led.write(0)
            elif charSplit[y] == "-":
#                led.write(1)
                time.sleep(0.50)
#                led.write(0)
            elif charSplit[y] == "|":
                time.sleep(0.25)

message = Message(root, text="Enter Text to Turn to Morse Code: ", width=200)
message.configure(font=("Arial", 10))
message.place(x=0, y=10)

button = Button(root, text="Turn to Morse Code", command=actLED, width=20, height=2)
button.place(x=180, y=60)

root.mainloop()
```